# How to find closely matching unique elements in two lists? (Using a distance function here)

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a name matcher to compare say, `'JOHN LEWIS'` to `'JOHN SMITH LEWIS'`. They are clearly the same person and I want to create a function where when you enter those names, it turns it into a list then gives you the matching names.

The problem is that my loop is returning that `'LEWIS'` matches with `'LEWIS'` and `'SMITH'` matches with `'LEWIS'` because of the order that it is in.

```
from pyjarowinkler import distance

entered_name = 'JOHN LEWIS'.split(' ')  # equals ['JOHN','LEWIS']
system_name = 'JOHN SMITH LEWIS'.split(' ')  # equals ['JOHN','SMITH','LEWIS']

ratio = []

for i in entered_name:
    maximum = 0 
    for j in system_name:
        score = distance.get_jaro_distance(i, j, winkler=True, 
                                           scaling=0.1)
        while score > maximum:
            maximum = score
            new = (i, j, maximum)
            system_name.remove(i) 
            #removes that name from the original list
    ratio.append(new)
```

would return something like: `[('JOHN', 'JOHN', 1.0), ('LEWIS', 'SMITH', 0.47)]`

and not: `[('JOHN', 'JOHN', 1.0), ('LEWIS', 'LEWIS', 1.0)]` <- this is what I want.

Also, if you try something like `'ALLY A ARM'` with `'ALLY ARIANA ARMANI'`, it matches `'ALLY'` twice if you don't do that `remove(i)` line. This is why I only want unique matches!

I just keep getting errors or the answers that I am not looking for.

Comment: Just a note, modifying a list while you are iterating through the list can lead to unexpected behavior. Working on it, but your `system_name.remove(i)` line might be dangerous.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but then I don't get the right Unique matches as I mentioned with the 'Ally' name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your `system_name.remove(i)` line. First of all, it's usually a bad idea to modify a list *while you're iterating through that list*. This can lead to unexpected behavior. In your case, here's what your code is doing:

1. First time through, matches `'JOHN'`, and `'JOHN'`. No problem.
2. Removes `'JOHN'` from `system_name`. Now `system_name = ['SMITH', 'LEWIS']`.
3. Second time through, `i = 'LEWIS'`, `j = 'SMITH'`, `score = .47` which is greater than 0, so your check `score > maximum` passes
4. We set `maximum = score`
5. We set `new = ('LEWIS', 'SMITH', 0.47)`
6. We remove `'LEWIS'` from `system_name`. Now `system_name = ['SMITH']`. Uh oh...

Simple rewrite below, using an `if` instead of a `while` loop because the `while` loop is totally unnecessary:

```
for i in entered_name:
    maximum = 0 
    for j in system_name:
        score = distance.get_jaro_distance(i, j, winkler=True, 
                                           scaling=0.1)
        if score > maximum:
            maximum = score
            new = (i, j, maximum)
    system_name.remove(new[1])  # want to remove 'SMITH' in the example, not 'LEWIS' 
    ratio.append(new)
```

All I did was move the `system_name.remove()` call outside of the loop over `system_name`, and replace `i` with `j` (using `new[1]` since I'm outside of the `j` loop).

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much for such a thorough answer, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Jaro-Winkler distance is for comparison of sequences, there is no need to compare individual elements as if you were trying to find an edit distance between individual characters rather than whole words.

With that in mind, one should probably treat parts of a name as individual letters, and the whole name as a word, comparing, say, `"JL"` vs. `"JSL"` instead of `"JOHN LEWIS"` and `"JOHN SMITH LEWIS"`:

```py
import string
import itertools

from pyjarowinkler import distance


WORDS_CACHE = {}


def next_letter():
    base = ""
    while True:
        for ch in string.ascii_lowercase:
            yield base + ch
        base += ch


GENERATOR = next_letter()


def encode(word):
    if word not in WORDS_CACHE:
        WORDS_CACHE[word] = GENERATOR.next()
    return WORDS_CACHE[word]


def score(first_name, second_name):
    return distance.get_jaro_distance(
        "".join(map(encode, first_name.split())),
        "".join(map(encode, second_name.split())),
    )
```